# Zoom to fit pushpins in Bing Maps?

Tags: bing-maps

Given a bunch of pushpins in Bing Maps, is there a quick and easy way to zoom in on those pushpins such that they are all visible, and fairly spread out? For example, say I have hundreds of pins all over Australia. Then I would want to zoom in to Australia as a continent, but seeing other continents would be too big, yet seeing only Sydney would be too small.

Comment: This is often called "Zoom to Extents (of the layer or data)"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The solution to this is to set the **bounds** property of the **[viewOptions](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg427628.aspx)** object.

The bounds property takes a **locationRect**. Since I knew the maximum and minimum longitudes and latitudes, I used the fromEdges constructor. There are other ways of making a locationRect, go [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg427621.aspx) for more information on how to make a locationRect.

Once you have the locationRect, simply set the bounds property either at the initial creation of the map, or later using the setView method for the map class. Here is my code:

`box=new Microsoft.Maps.LocationRect.fromEdges(maxLat,minLong,minLat,maxLong);
 map=new Microsoft.Maps.Map(document.getElementById("mapDiv"), {
     credentials:"Your bing map developer key",
     bounds: box
 });`